# Seeing a lot of SendGrid Activity marked "Deferred" after disabling a mailbox

Tags: azure, sendgrid, email-spam, mailboxer

Using SendGrid through Azure (free version).

I recently disabled a user's email because it was receiving way too much SPAM. Prior to doing this my activities list was about 1-2 pages long with recognizable e-mails my system was sending out per customer input in a website (there is a workflow for forms which the user inputs, then my system sends out an e-mail confirming input).

Now that I have disabled that e-mail, I am seeing upwards of 59 pages of activity just for one day (since I disabled the e-mail address), most of which is listed as "Deferred" or "Processed". The lists include SPAM e-mail addresses (something-reverse-mortgage@whatever.net, etc.).

Reading the SendGrid documentation, it seems that "Deferred" activities just mean that the receiving ISP is asking SendGrid to slow down. I take this to mean that my server is sending these e-mails.

This is worrisome obviously. Disabling that e-mail has this unintended consequence of seeing hundreds of "Defered" activity listings in SendGrid.

I am confused, however, if this is just the system getting these e-mails and then trying to bounce them back through my server. Since it's SPAM and likely not a real e-mail address, is SendGrid just trying to return the e-mails? Hence the activity?

If so, is this something that will eventually die down, or should I do something to prevent SendGrid from returning these obviously bogus SPAM e-mails to what it thinks is the originating sender?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I send about 100K emails a month with sendgrid and I don't worry at all about deferred.  About 1/3 of my outgoing emails are gmail and gmail is very agressive at blocking emails when you send more than 50 or so at once.  They simply reject and sendgrid tries again later.  They all seem to go thru within about 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you for the response, and it's good to know that for email sending in general that it will eventually get sent, but in my situation I think I am seeing this because I have a disabled e-mail box. Maybe SendGrid wants to bounce back the originating e-mail, however, since those e-mails are SPAM without a real "From" e-mail address to notify, it just gets keeps trying to bounce it back out?

Comment: Hmm. not sure.  sounds like a question for sendgrid support.